# nClam - How to pass linux server path to ScanFileOnServer

Tags: c#, ubuntu, clam, nclam

I have set up ClamAv running in a docker container inside Ubuntu VM (VirtualBox). I have written the following C# program (running from my Windows Host) and able to scan local files in my windows machine successfully (SendAndScanFileAsync) as 192.168.0.103:3310 (ClamAv in Guest Ububtu) is accessible from Host Windows.

I want to scan the files on Linux server's Downloads folder using ScanFileOnServerAsync method but I am unable to do as I am not sure how to specify the Linux path in the following code. Please help.

```
namespace ClamAvDemo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var clam = new ClamClient("192.168.0.103", 3310);
            var scanResult = clam.ScanFileOnServerAsync("Downloads"); // Downloads is a folder in Linux Server running as a VM

            switch (scanResult.Result.Result)
            {
                case ClamScanResults.Clean:
                    Console.WriteLine("The file is clean!");
                    break;
                case ClamScanResults.VirusDetected:
                    Console.WriteLine("Virus Found!");
                    Console.WriteLine("Virus name: {0}", scanResult.Result.InfectedFiles.First().VirusName);
                    break;
                case ClamScanResults.Error:
                    Console.WriteLine("Woah an error occured! Error: {0}", scanResult.Result.RawResult);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Linux server path to scan: /home/{user}/Downloads

Whatever be the path format I specify, I always get this error - "Downloads: lstat() failed: No such file or directory. ERROR"

Comment: This stuff is helpful

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify the full file path, like `"/home/username/Downloads/filename.ext"`.